# "the things which your eyes have seen"

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 4:9 (NASB)

> “Only be careful for yourself and watch over your soul diligently, so that you do not forget **the things which your eyes have seen** and they do not depart from your heart all the days of your life; but make them known to your sons and your grandsons.

What are "the things which your eyes have seen"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"the things which your eyes have seen" is a direct allusion to the central focus of the Jewish religion - they worshiped an all-powerful but invisible God who does visible miracles to demonstrate His power and presence.

Some of the tings which they had seen might include:

- The plagues of Egypt and how the Israelites were spared and saved
- The miraculous escape from Egypt and the parting of the red sea
- Manna and quail
- water from the rock
- the giving of the law at Sinai and the supernatural manifestation that accompanied it
- the glory of the LORD that appeared in the tabernacle (Ex 40)
- the bronze snake (Num 21)
- The pillar of cloud by day and the pillar of fire by night leading the nation

These were all powerful evidences that God both existed and deserved their sole worship, Deut 6:4, 5.

This whole phenomenon of visible miracles is again referenced in Deut 10:21 -

> He is the one you praise; he is your God, who performed for you those
> great and awesome wonders you saw with your own eyes.

There is a further reference to this in Acts 7:36 as part of Stephen's final speech -

> He led them out of Egypt and performed wonders and signs in Egypt, at
> the Red Sea and for forty years in the wilderness.

These visible signs and wonders that God performed during the Exodus became proverbial in Israel - Deut 7:19, 26:8, 29:3, 34:11, Neh 9:10, Ps 105:27, 135:9, Jer 32:20, 21.